# Remove newline character in bash

Tags: git, bash

I'm writing a script to automatically manage my git email configuration.  Within my script I would like to output a message notifying the user that the email configuration has changed.  I am using the command `git config user.email` to get the new email address.  However, it prints it to a newline.  I would like to print it to the same line as my message.

This is what I have now:

```
    echo "Email not configured to Work in Work directory.";
    git config user.email "myworkemail@myworkemail.com"
    echo "Git email configuration has now been changed to "
    git config user.email
```

Comment: Have you tried telling `echo` to not print the newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a subshell substitution like this:

```
echo "Email not configured to Work in Work directory.";
git config user.email "myworkemail@myworkemail.com"
echo "Git email configuration has now been changed to \"$(git config user.email)\""
```

Answer (score 1):

`help echo`:

> Options:
>   **-n        do not append a newline**
>     -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
>     -E        explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: `-s` is not a supported option in `bash`'s built-in `echo`.

Comment: Because question is tagged with `bash` I suggest to use `help echo` for this builtin command.

Comment: @chepner You are right, but `-s` isn't the option in question here.

Comment: Then why mention it at all?

Comment: @chepner because I copied the output from man assuming they were the same options.